# cant import beautiful soup 4 in virtual env

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to install use beautiful soup in a virtual environment.  I have successfully installed the module using both pip and easy_install but I cannot seem to import it into the interpreter.  Here is what I did to try and launch it..  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

```
(WebScraper)test@ubuntu:~/code/WebScraper$ easy_install beautifulsoup4
Searching for beautifulsoup4
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/beautifulsoup4/  
Reading http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/
Reading http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/
Best match: beautifulsoup4 4.2.0
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/b/beautifulsoup4/beautifulsoup4-    4.2.0.tar.gz#md5=48a3a7ee42d9b5bd046b3b5c86bb2d35
Processing beautifulsoup4-4.2.0.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-R6wbsM/beautifulsoup4-4.2.0/setup.cfg
Running beautifulsoup4-4.2.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-    R6wbsM/beautifulsoup4-4.2.0/egg-dist-tmp-xIc3Vf
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Adding beautifulsoup4 4.2.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/test/code/WebScraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.2.0-  py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for beautifulsoup4
Finished processing dependencies for beautifulsoup4
(WebScraper)test@ubuntu:~/code/WebScraper$ python

Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:28:01) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bs4
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "bs4.py", line 1, in <module>
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: cannot import name BeautifulSoup
>>>>
```

Comment: Interesting. Just done the same thing on my ubuntu in a brand new virtualenv - imported `bs4` without any errors.

Comment: Could try to do the same thing in a brand new virtualenv?

Comment: hmm.  That seemed to work.  Thanks for the advice.  I moved my project to the new virtual env and everything worked fine

Comment: It seems like you've installed new bs4 on top of the old bs4 in your virtualenv. So, uninstalling+installing bs4 should work too.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
dirk@discordia:~/Dokumente/devel/python$ virtualenv blabla --no-site-packages
New python executable in blabla/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
dirk@discordia:~/Dokumente/devel/python$ source blabla/bin/activate
(blabla)dirk@discordia:~/Dokumente/devel/python$ cd blabla/
(blabla)dirk@discordia:~/Dokumente/devel/python/blabla$ pip install yolk
Downloading/unpacking yolk
  Downloading yolk-0.4.3.tar.gz (86kB): 86kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/home/dirk/Dokumente/devel/python/blabla/build/yolk/setup.py) egg_info for package yolk

...snip...  

Successfully installed yolk
Cleaning up...

(blabla)dirk@discordia:~/Dokumente/devel/python/blabla$ yolk -l
Python          - 2.7.5+       - active development (/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload)
argparse        - 1.2.1        - active development (/usr/lib/python2.7)
pip 1.5.4 has no metadata
setuptools 2.2 has no metadata
wsgiref         - 0.1.2        - active development (/usr/lib/python2.7)
yolk            - 0.4.3        - active 
(blabla)dirk@discordia:~/Dokumente/devel/python/blabla$ pip install beautifulsoup4
Downloading/unpacking beautifulsoup4
  Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.3.2.tar.gz (143kB): 143kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/home/dirk/Dokumente/devel/python/blabla/build/beautifulsoup4/setup.py) egg_info for package beautifulsoup4

Installing collected packages: beautifulsoup4
  Running setup.py install for beautifulsoup4

Successfully installed beautifulsoup4
Cleaning up...
(blabla)dirk@discordia:~/Dokumente/devel/python/blabla$ python
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:37:08) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bs4 ; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
```

So maybe you want to try a new virtenv and install bs4 with `pip install`.